# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Comparison::setParameter()

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, query-builder

first i use ZF2 and i'm using QueryBuilder method in a controller in order to extract data from DataBase and send it with JSON.

```
      $em = $this->getServiceLocator()-> get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
            $repo = $em->getRepository('Login\Entity\Doctor');
            $queryBuilder = $repo->createQueryBuilder('d');
            $queryBuilder->select('d');
            $queryBuilder->where($queryBuilder->expr()->eq('firstname', 
             ':firstname')->setParameter('firstname', $firstname))
                         ->andwhere($queryBuilder->expr()->eq('lastname', 
             ':lastname')->setParameter('lastname', $lastname))
                         ->andwhere($queryBuilder->expr()->eq('city', 
             ':city')->setParameter('city', $city))
                         ->andwhere($queryBuilder->expr()->eq('speciality', 
             ':speciality')->setParameter('speciality', $speciality));
            $queryBuilder>getQuery()>setHydrationMode(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
            $result = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
            return new JsonModel($result);
```

and this gave me a Call Stack error and that setParameter is not defined.

Comment: It looks like a parenthesis error: Try $queryBuilder->where($queryBuilder->expr()->eq('firstname',':firstname'))->setParameter('firstname', $firstname)

Answer (score 0):

the querybuilder has a method `setParameter`, the expressions however do not. you call `setParameter` on the `expr()` return values.

so turn

```
)->setParameter(...))
```

into

```
))->setParameter(...)
```

and it should work.